# How can I configure Google App Engine to not build some Go files?

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-app-engine-go

I am trying to deploy a set of Google Talk slides to Google App Engine. Some of my example files have build errors on purpose, but I can't deploy these to Google App Engine because it complains that they don't build.

Supposedly I should be able to set `nobuild_files: [some_regex]` in my app.yaml, but it's not working. I did have to switch to the `goapp` tool for deploying because of another issue with the `vendor` folder, so that could be related, IDK.

I tried adding a `// +build !appengine` to the top of my Go file with the issue, but it didn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Put your non-compiling code in directory called `testdata` and it will be ignored by the Go toolchain.

Answer (score 0):

The nobuild_files in the app.yaml file should work as specified 
[here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/refdocs/google.appengine.api.appinfo#google.appengine.api.appinfo.AppInfoExternal.nobuild_files) and are able to see format and configuration of the app.yaml [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/config/appref#skip_files), such as:

```html
nobuild_files:
- ^(.*/)?#.*#$
- ^(.*/)?.*~$
- ^(.*/)?.*\.py[co]$
- ^(.*/)?.*/RCS/.*$
- ^(.*/)?\..*$
- ^(.*/)?.*\.bak$
```